# Problema con menu responsive en CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

hace unos dias termine un menu responsive para mi pagina web, el problema es que al "esconderse" utilizando la propiedad de

```
right:-380px;
```

Este menu se oculta de forma correcta, pero toda la web me queda con un overflow y, es decir, se puede scrolear hacia el costado, tenia entendido que al tener la propiedad de position absolute, esto no deberia pasar, dejo el codigo:

```
    header nav ul:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
  }
  header nav .responsive {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
  }

header .responsive-menu {   // Este es el menu responsive, empieza en -320px a la derecha para la animacion
    position: absolute;
    right: -320px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 93.2vh;
    background: #aa6ff8;
    -webkit-transition: 320ms;
    transition: 320ms;
    margin-top: -1px;
  }

  header .hide { //Este es el codigo que se agrega al hacer click en el boton
    right: 0;
  }
```

---

Codigo JS:

```
function responsive(){
let responsive = document.getElementById("menu-responsive")
console.log(responsive)

if (responsive.classList.contains("hide")){
    responsive.classList.remove("hide")
} else {
    responsive.classList.add("hide");
}
}
```

Y el HTML:

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Contacto</a></li>
                <button>Ingresar</button>
                <button>Registrarse</button>
            </ul>
            <button onclick="responsive()" class="icon"></button>

        </nav>

        <div id="menu-responsive" class="responsive-menu hide">

        </div>
```

La animacion y el boton funcionan correctamente, solo que no logro comprender el por que del overflow, muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Si pones al elemento padre `overflow: hidden` debería quitar el scroll

Answer (score -1):

No puedo ver el contenido además del header, pero armé un concepto en donde el menú es parte del contenedor principal y que este a su vez tiene la propiedad:

`position: relative;`

Esto pondrá un límite al menú para que no se salga del contenedor padre.

Comparto código de ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    header nav ul:nth-child(1) {
      display: none;
    }

    .responsive {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .responsive-menu {
      position: absolute;
      right: -320px;
      width: 320px;
      height: 93.2vh;
      background: #aa6ff8;
      -webkit-transition: 320ms;
      transition: 320ms;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }

    .container .hide {
      right: 0;
    }

    .container {
      color: azure;
      position: relative;
      width: 100vw;
      max-width: 100vw;
      height: 93.2vh;
      background: red;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a class="active" href="index.html">Sobre nosotros</a>

      <a href="index.html">Servicios</a>

      <a href="index.html">Contacto</a>

      <button>Ingresar</button>
      <button>Registrarse</button>

      <button onclick="responsive()" class="icon">Menú</button>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="menu-responsive" class="responsive-menu hide"></div>
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
    <script>
      function responsive() {
        let responsive = document.getElementById('menu-responsive');

        if (responsive.classList.contains('hide')) {
          responsive.classList.remove('hide');
        } else {
          responsive.classList.add('hide');
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que tal Victor, en tu respuesta tambien se ve como el menu responsive se esconde hacia el costado, y si haces scroll lo puedes ver, te pasa lo mismo que a mi.

Comment: Efectivamente! Agregué la propiedad de `overflow-x: hidden` al contenedor padre, echa un vistazo al código de ejemplo. Esto evita que aparezca un scroll en el eje horizaontal. Espero que sirva.